# Book series about British soldiers traveling to alternate Earths to find technology

Tags: story-identification, books, alternate-history

Back in the 80s I read a series about British soldiers traveling to alternate Earths to find technology.

Since it had a British protagonist, I'm assuming it was a British author.

Comment: Sliders meets SG1 meets Downton Abbey

Comment: Sliders meets SG1 is actually a good description

Comment: This reminds me of a question I answered before. In that case, the correct answer was the Richard Blade series of adventure novels, named after the protagonist, a British ex-soldier, now working for MI6, who was sent to a different parallel world in each volume in the search for new technology which could be beneficial back home. I don't know if it's the one you're thinking of, but you can read my old answer and see if anything rings a bell. https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/271737/story-identification-50s-60s-pulp-scifi-fiction-series-involving-dimensional-tra/271753#271753

Comment: That's it. Thank you. I did a search but evidently didn't do it well enough

Answer (score 7):

Possibly Michael Moorcock's [*Nomad of the Time Streams*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Nomad_of_the_Time_Streams)

> A Nomad of the Time Streams is a compilation volume of Michael Moorcock's early steampunk trilogy, begun in 1971 with *The Warlord of the Air* and continued by its 1974 and 1981 sequels, *The Land Leviathan* and *The Steel Tsar*. The trilogy follows the adventures of Edwardian-era British Army Captain Oswald Bastable in alternate versions of the 20th century.

> In the first book, Warlord of the Air, Bastable finds himself transported to an alternate late-20th century Earth where the European powers did not stir each other into a World War and in which the mighty airships of a British Empire on which the sun never sets are threatened by the rise of new and terrible enemies.

> In The Land Leviathan, Bastable visits an alternate 1904 in which most of the Western world has been devastated around the turn of the 20th century by a short, yet terrible war fought with futuristic devices and in which also biological weapons were used.

> In the final book, The Steel Tsar, Bastable witnesses an alternate 1941 where Great Britain and Germany became allies around the turn of the 20th century and thus neither the War of 1914 nor the October Revolution took place.